# Why won't my bash script work even though I think I am doing everything right? No matter where I look I cannot find an answer

Tags: bash, syntax

```
#! /bin/bash/

# this is a comment

date=$(date)
list=$(ls -la)

echo "date or list?"

read var

if [[ $var=$date ]]
then
        echo "Today's date: $date"

elif [[ $var=$list ]]
then
        echo "Listing all: $list"

else
        echo "Input not recognized"

fi
```

I've tried changing the if and elif statements multiple times. I want it to print the date when I type date and print ls -la when I type list.

Comment: `[[ $var = "$date" ]]` -- note the spaces around the `=`. (The quotes on the right-hand side are for a more obscure reason: without them, the operation is treated like a glob expression instead of an exact string match; it may be easier just to be in the habit of always using quotes on both sides).

Comment: Also, if you want to see if the user entered the exact string "date", you want `[[ $var = date ]]`, not `[[ $var = $date ]]`.

Comment: BTW, take the title of the question this was closed as a duplicate of as an example to try to use in your own questions in the future -- see how it's very specific to the individual technical problem at hand. Even if you don't understand the immediate cause well enough to write _that_ specific a question, the closer you can get the better your question will be at getting direct attention from folks qualified to answer it.